# Using the cons operator "|" with Keyword lists

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to define a function where I specify part of a keyword list, and then match the remaining opts as the tail.

```
def my_func(foo: 22, bar: 42 | baz) do
  IO.inspect(baz)
end

my_func(foo: 22, bar: 42, another_arg: 11, even_more_args: 12)
```

and the idea is for `baz` to be a keyword list that contains [another_arg: 11, even_more_args: 12]

This doesn't compile, failing with the following error:

> misplaced operator |/2
>
> The | operator is typically used between brackets as the cons operator:
>
> [head | tail]

However, I can pattern match a keyword list using the following:

```
def my_func([{:foo, 22}, {:bar, 42} | baz]) do
end
```

Since Keywords are semantic sugar for lists-of-tuples, it's not clear to me why the latter syntax works, but not the former. Is there some syntax I'm missing to be able to use `|` with keywords?

Comment: Maybe the best answer is use a Map `%{}` as that has much better semantics w.r.t partial matching on function signatures, but would love to hear if any options exist for Keyword lists.

Comment: lists keep the order while maps don't, if you don't care about the order of items you should use map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because the keyword list syntax is valid **only** in context of a list, meaning that such syntax is invalid:

```
iex> test = foo: 22
** (SyntaxError) iex:8:8: syntax error before: foo
```

But this is valid:

```
iex> test = [foo: 22]
[foo: 22]
def my_func([[foo: 22], [bar: 42] | baz]) do
end
```

Of course the previous syntax is not suitable since it will make nested lists, however you cannot use keywords without a list, so you have to explicitly write it as a tuple.

What I would recommend is using the [`++/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#++/2) operator:

```
def my_func([foo: 22, bar: 42] ++ rest) do
  IO.inspect(rest)
end
```